# Create an array list which will have flag based on old data and new data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in which different controls are there like : radio button, drop-down, textbox, texarea, checkboxes, images. Controls are not fix, either it may 10 or it may 50+ they are dynamic loaded sometimes.

Here i want to check for old data and new data. 
Let's say data in loaded in this controls. And when user click on this any control it will add old data in some array and when change that data it will compare with old data.
If data is not changed then it will set flag to false else set to true and create an array in that it has control name and flag.

I do not have created any form and didn't add any effort to achieve it. I just planing to do it.

I want to do like this. How is it possible using javascript orjQuery? Or is there any alternative to achieve this?

Comment: just create a variable for each control and on page load save the initial value in that variable.

Comment: Give a better explanation of *Controls are not fix, either it may 10 or it may 50+*. Are they dinamically loaded?

Comment: Also share an example of your markup and show your effort as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data()` method to hold the old value with each control, and maintain this old value on controls' change events.

```
$( "anyControl" ).data( "bar", { mydata: "test", score: 40 } ); //set data 

$( "anyControl" ).data("bar"); // get data
```

Comment: How does this mydata and score will come. On which event it will fetch mydata and compare new data that are modified?